# pandas how to compare similar rows and then drop by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
dfs = """
    contract  RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate   Valindex0
1  A00118  46   19000100      19880901  19841231          50
2  A00118  46   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
3  A00118  47   19000100      19880901  19831231          47
4  A00118  47   19840100      19880901  19841299          47
5  A00118  47   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
6  A00253  48   19000100      19820101  19811231          47
7  A00253  48   19820100      19820101  19841299          47
8  A00253  48   19850100      19820101  99999999          50
9  A00253  50   19000100      19820101  19781231          47
10 A00253  50   19790100      19820101  19841299          47
11 A00253  50   19850100      19820101  99999999          50
12 A00253  4L   20170101      19880901  99999999          39


"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfs.strip()), sep='\s+', 
                  dtype={"RB": str, "BeginDate": int, "EndDate": int,'ValIssueDate':int,'Valindex0':int})
```

df:

```
   contract RB  BeginDate   ValIssueDate    EndDate Valindex0
1   A00118  46  19000100    19880901    19841231    50
2   A00118  46  19850100    19880901    99999999    50
3   A00118  47  19000100    19880901    19831231    47
4   A00118  47  19840100    19880901    19841299    47
5   A00118  47  19850100    19880901    99999999    50
6   A00253  48  19000100    19820101    19811231    47
7   A00253  48  19820100    19820101    19841299    47
8   A00253  48  19850100    19820101    99999999    50
9   A00253  50  19000100    19820101    19781231    47
10  A00253  50  19790100    19820101    19841299    47
11  A00253  50  19850100    19820101    99999999    50
12 A00253  4L   20170101      19880901  99999999    39
```

I want to drop rows by this condition:

if this row has the same 'contract' and 'RB' with other row, but its 'ValIssueDate' is not between
'BeginDate' and 'EndDate',then drop this row.

**Notice the last row,it has unique RB so it should not be dropped.**

```
index_names = df[ (df['ValIssueDate'] <= df['EndDate'] ) | (df['ValIssueDate'] >= df['BeginDate'])].index
# drop these given row
# indexes from dataFrame
df.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
```

This method only compares within 1 row, but how to compare different rows with my conditions ?

The output should be:

```
    contract  RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate   Valindex0
2  A00118  46   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
5  A00118  47   19850100      19880901  99999999          50
7  A00253  48   19820100      19820101  19841299          47
10 A00253  50   19790100      19820101  19841299          47
12 A00253  4L   20170101      19880901  99999999          39
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dropping the rows you don't need, keep the rows you need.
The boolean indexing you did comes very close to what you actually need:

1. For rows where the contract and RB are duplicated, use the condition on ValIssueDate
2. For rows with unique contract and RB, keep all rows.

```
df = df[((df.duplicated(subset = ["contract", "RB"], keep=False)) & 
         (df['ValIssueDate'] <= df['EndDate'] ) & 
         (df['ValIssueDate'] >= df['BeginDate'])) | 
        ~df.duplicated(subset = ["contract", "RB"], keep=False)]

>>> df
   contract  RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate  Valindex0
2    A00118  46   19850100      19880901  99999999         50
5    A00118  47   19850100      19880901  99999999         50
7    A00253  48   19820100      19820101  19841299         47
10   A00253  50   19790100      19820101  19841299         47
12   A00253  4L   20170101      19880901  99999999         39
```